# Executiong closure on array modification

Tags: swift

I have the following code:

```
class Note: NSObject {
}

struct Global {
    static var notes: Array<Note> = [] {
        didSet {
            print("hi")
        }
    }
}
```

This prints "hi" if I add or remove an item from the array or if I do

```
Global.notes = []
```

Is there a way to print("hi") every time when one of the Note objects in the array is modified?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Is `Note` a value or a reference type (struct or class)?

Comment: Note is a class

Comment: This is a task for notifications. Or make `Note` a struct too.

Comment: Maybe add _Property observers_ to `Note` class properties. But if there are a lot of properties then it will be a mess

Comment: @swiftlynx If you make `Note` a struct (value-type) then the array's `didSet` property observer will be called because `Array` being a value-type too will cause it to change as well. But then it can't subclass `NSObject`. So... I guess you will need to look into KVO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing the `class` to a `struct`, I have two basic ways to handle this.

This is the object you asked about

```
class Note: NSObject {
}

struct Global {
    static var notes: Array<Note> = [] {
        didSet {
            print("hi")
        }
    }
}
```

Wrap `Notes` in a wrapper that is a struct to get the struct behavior.

```
extension Note {
    struct Wrapper { let note: Note }
}

extension Global {
    static var wrappedNotes = [Note.Wrapper]() {
        didSet {
            print("hi")
        }
    }
}

Global.wrappedNotes.append(Note.Wrapper(note: Note()))
Global.wrappedNotes[0] = Note.Wrapper(note: Note())
Global.wrappedNotes.remove(at: 0)
```

The other way is to create a note manager to wrap access to the array.

```
class NoteManager {

    subscript(index: Int) -> Note {
        get {
            return values[index]
        }
        set {
            defer { onUpdate() }
            values[index] = newValue
        }
    }

    func append(_ newNote: Note) {
        defer { onUpdate() }
        values.append(newNote)
    }

    func remove(at index: Int) -> Note {
        defer { onUpdate() }
        return values.remove(at: index)
    }

    private func onUpdate() {
        print("hi")
    }

    private var values = [Note]()

}

extension Global {
    static var managedNotes = NoteManager()
}

Global.managedNotes.append(Note())
Global.managedNotes[0] = Note()
Global.managedNotes.remove(at: 0)
```

Comment: OP's original code has the exact same output as both your given solutions. Adding/removing/replacing elements in `Global.notes` will trigger `didSet` with or without `Note.Wrapper`

Comment: @staticVoidMan I was providing other options for times when a class could not be turned into a struct.

Answer (score 0):

As per @staticVoidMan comment , If you make your model , a struct, rather than a class, then the *property observer* `didSet` will work for your `Note` model's own properties as well.

```
import Foundation

struct Note {
    var name: String
}

struct Global {
    static var notes: Array<Note> = [] {
        didSet {
                print("hi")            
        }
    }
}

Global.notes.append(Note(name: "Shubham"))
Global.notes.append(Note(name: "Bakshi"))
Global.notes[0].name = "Boxy"
```

This will print the following on the console :

> hi
>
> hi
>
> hi

Answer (score 0):

Swift `Array` is a `struct`, and `struct`s are value-type which means they change completely when elements are added/removed/replaced. Hence when you add/remove/replace a `Note`, the `didSet` property observer gets called as the array has been `set` again.

However, as per you question:

> Is there a way to print("hi") every time when one of the Note objects in the array is modified?

By this I am assuming that you want to do something when an element within this array is accessed and an internal property is modified.

This would have been fine if you were dealing with only value-type objects, i.e. had your `Note` object also been a `struct`, then changing anything inside one `Note` would have caused the array to change as well.
But your `Note` object is a class, i.e. reference-type, and stays as the same object even if it's internal elements change. Hence your array doesn't need to update and `didSet` does not get called.
<sub>[Read: Value and Reference Types](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10)</sub>

---

### KVO Solution:

Now... Since your `Note` is subclassing `NSObject`, you can use the [KVO concept](https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/swift/property-key-value-observer/)

As per the following working example, we observe only one property of the `Note` class.
*If you want to observe more properties then you will need to observe those many more keypaths*.

#### Example:

```
class Note: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var content = ""
    
    init(_ content: String) {
        self.content = content
    }
}

class NoteList {
    var notes: [Note] = [] {
        didSet {
            print("note list updated")
            
            //register & save observers for each note
            self.noteMessageKVOs = notes.map { (note) -> NSKeyValueObservation in
                return note.observe(\Note.content, options: [.new, .old]) { (note, value) in
                    print("note updated: \(value.oldValue) changed to \(value.newValue)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    //array of observers
    var noteMessageKVOs = [NSKeyValueObservation]()
}

let list = NoteList()
list.notes.append(Note("A"))   //note list updated
list.notes.append(Note("B"))   //note list updated
list.notes[0].content = "X"    //note updated: A changed to X
list.notes[1].content = "Y"    //note updated: B changed to Y
```

Notes:

- `NSObject` is required for KVO
- `@objc dynamic` is required to make a property observable
- `\Note.message` is a keypath
- `noteMessageKVOs` are required to keep the observers alive